# trigger fb-login automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook

I use fb:login-button social plugin to authenticate the user.

However when user go to some pages that requires user to be authenticated, I'd like to trigger the fb:login-button automatically.

How can I do this in javascript? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how your code is structured, it's hard to say, but it's pretty easy using [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
<fb:login-button blah="blah"></fb:login-button>
<script>
    $("fb\:login-button").trigger("click");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I add these to my code and it doesn't work as expect. When we click on <fb:login-button>, it should show up a window to login, but no action when I use jquery to trigger it. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fb:login-button is rendered with an iframe, so you can't trigger the click on the facebook object. I think you should use the facebook object (if it is possible).